# The top border of tablix is getting truncated in ssrs report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which prints all the parameters provided in the end of the report inside a tablix. We have a page header which is printed on all the pages. The top border of my tablix is getting truncated no matter what i try , but if the printonlastpage property for page header is set as false, i can see the top border. What can be the issue behind this. I have tried resizing the tablix and headers, still no use

Comment: Maybe share an image of the issue? I'm struggling to visualize the problem

Comment: Is the tablix all the way up the top with the header boder? If so, have you tried moving the tablix down so it doesn't thouch the header?