# Top border of a rectangle with "add page break before" doesn't show in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have checked this other link but there are no updates there: [The top border of tablix is getting truncated in ssrs report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443761/the-top-border-of-tablix-is-getting-truncated-in-ssrs-report)

Report Layout:

1. One large header rectangle with textboxes in it.
2. One tablix that spans the entire width of the page with some margins left on the sides.
3. Two smaller tablixes one below the other.
4. One wide rectangle with two textboxes in it.
5. One wide rectangle with a single textbox in it. This one contains just a large amount of text.

Problem: Rectangle in 5) above is set to have a page break before it, so it will always show up on the last page. But when I run the report in Report Builder, I never see the top border of the rectangle. Every rectangle / grid as a gap of 1mm between them so there is no overlapping.

Anyone has ideas?

Edit:
Other information:
Orientation: Landscape
Report Size: 29.7cm X 21cm
Page Body Size: 29.3cm X 21cm

Comment: I believe I have come across this issue before, but I cannot remember if and how I resolved it. If you are still having issues with this, I have a question: Have you tried setting borders on the textbox within the rectangle rather than setting them directly on the rectangle?